# How to convert unmanaged delta tables to managed without creating metastore?

Tags: azure-databricks

I could find out that we have two options in Databricks for Tables.

1. Managed tables ( where metadata and files both will be in hive data storage)
2. Unmanaged tables ( where metadata will be in data bricks and files will be in external storage)

But I am looking for {where  metadata(delta) with managed tables but location should be external }, can you suggest me a way to do so?
As I know it can be achieved by creating Metastore-ADLS ( is there any other way for doing this activity?)

[image: img1]

```
 (Create table bank_delta2 using delta location ‘dbfs:/filestore/……)
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed tables are created in a "**default**" location, and both the data and table metadata are handled by either Hive metastore or Unity Catalog.
When you drop a managed table, both the table definition and the actual data are deleted.

On the other hand, unmanaged tables(External tables) differ in that only the metadata is controlled by Hive metastore or Unity Catalog.
If you drop an unmanaged table, only the table definition is removed, and the data remains unaffected.

To create an external table with SQL, specify a **LOCATION** path in your CREATE TABLE statement. External tables can use the following file formats:

**DELTA
CSV,
JSON,
AVRO,
PARQUET,
ORC,
TEXT**

To create an external table and populate it with data in your cloud storage, add a `LOCATION` clause:

```
CREATE TABLE <catalog>.<schema>.<table-name>
(
    <column-specification>
)
USING <format>
LOCATION 'abfss://<table-location>'
SELECT * from <format>.`abfss://<path-to-files>`;
```

**Reference:** [Create tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/create-tables#example-notebook-external-table)